# How to convert Time in String format ("12:45" or it can be "725:00" ) to minutes in java?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

i trying to convert time in string format to minutes. i can use substring and find the minutes but there is a problem because there is a chance of getting  time in the format  720:00 hours. (as i am calculating time for many days) pls help with me.... 
Thanks in advance........

Hussain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need to calculate how many minutes are in the given hours and minutes. Well, I'd do it fast and simple:

```
String time = "725:00";
String[] parts = time.split(":",2);
int hours = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
int minutes = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
return hours*60+minutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Groovy, you could do something like this:

```
def time = '720:00'
def minutes = time.split(':').with {
  (h,m) = it as int[]
  h * 60 + m
}
```

Comment: `(['720'] as String[]) as int[]` doesn't work with groovy 1.7.8.  Works with 1.7.6, though.  Using tokenize instead of split fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Java use `String.split(":")` and take the second element of the array.

Assuming that the time is in "hour:minute" format.